# Creating Visio 2016 shapes in C# add-in

Tags: c#, visio, office-addins

In my Visio add-in I create some shapes what has no geometry, only text. Following C# code is used to create texts in the center of Visio page:

```cs
Master MyMaster = MyStencil.Masters["Navigation"];

Shape MyShape = MyPage.Drop(MyMaster, PageRight / 2.0, PageTop / 2.0);

MyShape.Text = "Some text";

double ShapeLeft, ShapeBottom, ShapeRight, ShapeTop;

MyShape.BoundingBox((short)VisBoundingBoxArgs.visBBoxUprightText,
    out ShapeLeft, out ShapeBottom, out ShapeRight, out ShapeTop);
```

After the text shape is created its bounding box is calculated to generate other components of the page. That worked perfectly in earlier versions of Visio, but not in Visio 2016.

Text shape bounding box in Visio 2010 and Visio 2013 was:

```
ShapeLeft = 5.48
ShapeBottom = 4.05
ShapeRight = 6.20
ShapeTop = 4.21
```

Shape bounding box in Visio 2016 is:

```
ShapeLeft = 0.0
ShapeBottom = 0.0
ShapeRight = -1.0
ShapeTop = -1.0
```

What is wrong with method Shape.BoundingBox() in Visio 2016?

Thank you,

Sal

Comment: Hi, I confirm I see the same difference between 2013 and 2016 and have raised it with the Visio team.

Comment: @JohnGoldsmith -- did you hear any news from the Visio team? Do you think we can expect a fix of the problem in any incoming Office 2016 SP?

Comment: Hi, Just to update, that the fix for this appears to be on the way now: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3203473/july-5-2017-update-for-visio-2016-kb3203473

Comment: @JohnGoldsmith Thanks a lot! Bounding boxes are fixed now for Visio 2016. However, in Visio Pro environment we still get "0, 0, -1, -1". What is a way to fix that in a Pro version as well?

Answer (score 0):

I could repro this aswell but there are some details to this that suggest BoundingBox() is working fine in visio16,

Shape.BoundingBox() takes flag as first parameter which is as mentioned here "((short)Visio.VisBoundingBoxArgs.visBBoxUprightText" and that is used to get the bounding box of the rectangle that text encloses. Here is the catch, Shape.BoundingBox() method checks for the Shape.type() which in this case is returned as the rectangle and the flag says to get the bounding box for the text which ends up in a failure case and thus the output as observed.

Above statement can be validated with the info given here,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766755.aspx

"If the BoundingBox method returns an error, or if it is asked to return the rectangle enclosing zero shapes, the rectangle returned is { left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -1, top: -1 }; otherwise, the rectangle returned has left less than or equal to (<=) right, and bottom less than or equal to (<=) top. The numbers returned are in internal units (inches)."

Also to verify that BoundingBox() returns correct value we can try using the flag "visBBoxUprightWH" which gives the exact bounding box for the rectangle on which we are querying for the bounding box. (Code below)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
        Visio::Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Visio::Page page = application.ActivePage;
        Visio::Document basicStencil = application.Documents.OpenEx("basic_u.vssx", (short)(Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenRO | Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenHidden));
        var master = basicStencil.Masters.ItemU["Rectangle"];
        double pinX = 5.5;
        double pinY = 5.5;
        double height = 2.0;
        double width = 2.0;
        Visio::Shape shape = page.Drop(master, pinX, pinY);
        String text = "I am here";
        shape.Text = text;
        Visio.Cell cell = shape.get_CellsU("Height");
        cell.ResultIUForce = height;
        cell = shape.get_CellsU("Width");
        cell.ResultIUForce = width;


        double Left = 0.0;
        double Right = 0.0;
        double Bottom = 0.0;
        double Top = 0.0;
              shape.BoundingBox((short)Visio.VisBoundingBoxArgs.visBBoxDrawingCoords, out Left, out Bottom, out Right, out Top);
        Console.WriteLine(Left);     //4.5
        Console.WriteLine(Right);   //6.5
        Console.WriteLine(Bottom); //6.5
        Console.WriteLine(Top);       //4.5
}
```

visio internally first gets the temp rectangle of the text inside the actual rectangle and then calls the BoundingBox method on this temp rectangle shape whenever using the flag "visBBoxUprightText" while querying for the BoundingBox() which eventually works fine without any failure.

Comment: The BoundingBox method does work correctly for normal geometry, but not in the OP's case where the shape has no geometry.  The same code in 2013 performs as expected, so there is a difference between the two version which should not be there.

Comment: Did the further investigation and thus found there were some recent changes done to the Shape.BoundingBox() method that caused this. For a workaround Shape.VisualBoundingBox() can be used